# Remmina on Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 remote through Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 SSH

Tags: server, ssh, remmina, client

I have Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 (home) somewhere and ssh server Ubuntu 17.04 (have ssh key) with known white ip and a local network after the server with Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 (work) (grey ip) computer (also have ssh key on server).
Remmina client installed on remote (work) and (home) and connection accepted.
How can I connect to desktop from (home) to (work) using ssh?

Answer (score 0):

Not as in question but I found it works and solve the main.
If you work with linux desktop it is possible to run any application on guest comp via ssh terminal.
Someting like:
ssh user@server // connects to the server and than you are on local network;
ssh user@desktop // connects to the desktop;
and than maybe
nautilus --browser /home/user/ // or;
firefox
works good but slowly, still waiting for answer...